# Why not work the (TikZ) node with this code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmaker, nodes

I have this code, and I want to add node near by the points. But the texts is always on the 0,0 point.

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
    

    \begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0) node {A};
    \coordinate (B) at (7,0) node {B};
    \coordinate (C) at (7,3) node {C};
    \coordinate (D) at (0,3) node {D};
    \coordinate (E) at (0,4) node {E};
    \coordinate (F) at (7,4) node {F};
    \coordinate (G) at (7,7) node {G};
    \coordinate (H) at (0,7) node {H};
    \coordinate (I) at (1.5,5.5);
    \coordinate (J) at (1.5,1.5);
    
    \draw [thick, blue, dotted, fill=green!20] (A) rectangle (C);
    \draw (E) rectangle (G);
    \draw [thin, red, dotted, fill=blue!20] (J) circle (1.2);
    \draw (I) circle (1.2);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: result]

Thanks for reply!

Comment: `\coordinate` does not move the current point. USe `\path (0,0) coordinate(A) node{A};` instead (for example).

Comment: Thanks! It works! :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments